# using isNaN to evaluate input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using isNaN to evaluate input in text box my function is like this

```
function IsNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(n);
}
```

it's working fine with numeric but not on negative values nor decimal values like 1.2,

but I will not accept negative or decimal values like 1.2

how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: n is any type text in text box....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean

```
function IsPostiveInteger(n) {
  var n = new Number(n);
  return !isNaN(n) && n===parseInt(n,10) && n>0;
}
```

Comment: Actually the === is correct - it means that n not only has the same value but is the same type, e.g. an integer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Number(n)`. This will return NAN if its not a number. Else will return the same number irrespective of negative or positive

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Shorter</strike> Alternate solution:

```
function IsNumeric(n){
    // any valid number
    //return /^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(n);

    // only positive numbers
    //return /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(n);

    // only positive whole numbers
    return /^\d+$/.test(n);
}
```

Comment: But the asker does not want decimals nor negative values

Comment: @mplungjan: Yea, I was playing around with it after I saw the other's answers. Now It will only accept whole numbers. (as shown [on jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/VeXQP/))

Comment: You mean as in 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999